# When I load the same sound n times in Javascript, will the browser just get the sound from the server and then copy it to n different objects?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, loading

I use Javascript. For example:

```
sound = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 20; i ++)
    sound[i] = new Audio("source.wav");
```

Will the sound actually get retrieved from the server 20 times, or just once?

Specifically, I'm talking about Google Chrome, Opera, Safari, Opera and IE. All the mainstream, bigger, still active browsers. I'm asking because loading multiple versions of the same sound is a very important part of my game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depends upon the browser. Smart ones will just use ths cache...dumb ones won't

Comment: they aren't dumb, except for IE which I ain't sure of...probably because of bias against it, hehe. But seriously, IE also would be using cache, can't guarantee though